# Email content logs in server

Tags: linux, logging, server

Does Linux server by default save email body logs? i have checked `/var/logs/maillog` It only show sender info but not email body.

I am using rackspace hosting.

please help.

Comment: That obviously depends on what server software you use as SMTP server and how its configuration is.

Comment: You might find what you're looking for in `/var/spool/mail`

Comment: No, its only contain 4 empty files